# Handling collision in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hey guys I have been working on a little project of mine utilizing the awesome library `three.js`

Now I have been working with the example of https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html to handle collision detection, more so on when an object over laps another object utilizing `voxel's`.

To reference my problem I am using the http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_voxelpainter example.

Anyways to continue, when I render a `voxel` onto the screen, anything above the cube will allow me to render another `voxel` anything within a certain radius `below` the `volex` will not let me render:

[image: Underneath volex within certain radius will not render]

Here is shown above cube:
[image]

Now here is my neat little function I put together using the example provided by `stemkoski`:

```
        checkOverlapObject: function(voxel) // THIS IS USED TO SEE IF WE ARE OVER LAPPING ANY OBJECTS
        {
            var originPoint = voxel.position.clone();
            var collidableObjs = this.rooms;
            for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < voxel.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
            {       
                var localVertex = voxel.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
                console.log(localVertex);
                var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( voxel.matrix );
                console.log(globalVertex);

                var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( voxel.position );
                console.log(directionVector);

                console.log(originPoint);
                console.log(directionVector.clone().normalize());
                if(collidableObjs.length > 0)
                {
                    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
                    var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects( collidableObjs );
                    if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) 
                    {
                        console.log(collisionResults);
                        console.log(collisionResults[0].distance);
                        console.log( directionVector.length() );
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
```

Now what happens here is, before actually adding a rendered `volex` the user gets a preview of if they have permission to add the `volex`  So we pass a `volex` made by:

```
 var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( this.room.cubeGeometry, this.room.cubeTmpHoverMaterial );
 voxel.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
 voxel.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
 voxel.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
 voxel.material.color.setHex(this.colorTmpHover);
```

into our `checkOverlapObject` function to see if the object is overlapping a object that has been rendered onto the `screen/grid`

Now following my `little neat` function I made, I have placed `console.log` to output parameters and here is some of that output:

```
T…E.Vector3 {x: 25, y: 25, z: 25} <!-- our localVertex
T…E.Vector3 {x: 25, y: 25, z: 25} <!-- our globalVertex
T…E.Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: -350} <!-- our directionVector
T…E.Vector3 {x: 25, y: 25, z: 375} <!-- our originPoint
T…E.Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: -1} <!-- our directionVector.clone().normalize()
[Object, Object] <!-- our collisionResults
225 <!-- our collisionResults[0].distance
350 <!-- our directionVector.length()
```

This data is based off of the first picture.

Please understand that I have other `volex` that take up `2 blocks on the grid` or more.  So the reason for this is, I have a center location of the position but I need to take into account the rest of the object if it takes up `2 blocks on the grid` to check if that overlaps the `already rendered volex` I don't care if they touch each other.

Any suggestions or thoughts as to what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As asked above I finally found a solution.  I created a custom function for object `collision/overlap`.

Firstly, here is whats wrong with the above `collision` code as shown above, it process's the `raycaster` starting with the `direction` of our `object` - shooting a line straight across from its `orgin` to see if anything comes into contact with that `ray`.  Now that is great and  all but not very sufficient in telling when we have a `overlap/collision` if any part of the `object` is touching another `object`

As shwon with our `rays`:

[image: As described with our rays]

So here is my solution.

When ever we have an object on our plane, we know everything about it, our coordinates of `x,y,z` - I am not dealing with `y` in this example so ignore that.

What we care about is our objects `width = x` and our objects `depth/length = z`.  So in essence when we are checking to see if an object is `overlapping` another object we simply need to process through each `min x/z and max x/z` of our `to be added object` and our already `rendered obj`

How we do that is, loop through our object to be added `starting min z position` with a `for` loop. This starting `min z` position contains our `position z + min z of object`.  This gives us the exact `z` position on our `plane`.

We than move on to our `width` or our object to be added `starting min x position` with a `for` loop.  Don't forget our `x` gives us the exact position on our `plane`

Now the reason for this is simple.  We want to start at `position 0,0` of our object to be added.  Increment by one up our `length/z` - `increment` all the way down our `width/x` and while doing this process each object on our `plane` that is already rendered and check to see if any exact point matches ours.

Here is the actual method:

```
        checkOverlapObject: function(voxel) // THIS IS USED TO SEE IF WE ARE OVER LAPPING ANY OBJECTS
        {

            var collidableObjs = this.rooms; 
            //lets get our voxel min and max vars
            var voxelMX = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.max.x;
            var voxelMZ = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.max.z;
            var voxelmX = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
            var voxelmZ = voxel.geometry.boundingBox.min.z;
                // we need to get our voxel position ad to do some math to see if voxel min and max do not go beyound our boundries for our plane
            var voxelPX = voxel.position.x;
            var voxelPZ = voxel.position.z;

            var totalPositionVoxelminZ = (voxelPZ + voxelmZ);
            var totalPositionVoxelminX = (voxelPX + voxelmX);
            var totalPositionVoxelMAXZ = (voxelPZ + voxelMZ);
            var totalPositionVoxelMAXX = (voxelPX + voxelMX);

            // start loop for object to add Z cordinate
            for(var length = totalPositionVoxelminZ; length < totalPositionVoxelMAXZ; length++)
            {
                // start loop for object to add X cordinate
                for(var width = totalPositionVoxelminX; width < totalPositionVoxelMAXX; width++)
                {
                    for(var i = 0; i < collidableObjs.length;i++)
                    {
                        //lets get our voxel min and max vars
                        var thisvoxelMX = this.rooms[i].geometry.boundingBox.max.x;
                        var thisvoxelMZ = this.rooms[i].geometry.boundingBox.max.z;
                        var thisvoxelmX = this.rooms[i].geometry.boundingBox.min.x;
                        var thisvoxelmZ = this.rooms[i].geometry.boundingBox.min.z;
                            // we need to get our voxel position ad to do some math to see if voxel min and max do not go beyound our boundries for our plane
                        var thisvoxelPX = this.rooms[i].position.x;
                        var thisvoxelPZ = this.rooms[i].position.z;

                        var thistotalPositionVoxelminZ = (thisvoxelPZ + thisvoxelmZ);
                        var thistotalPositionVoxelminX = (thisvoxelPX + thisvoxelmX);
                        var thistotalPositionVoxelMAXZ = (thisvoxelPZ + thisvoxelMZ);
                        var thistotalPositionVoxelMAXX = (thisvoxelPX + thisvoxelMX);

                        for(var insideZ = thistotalPositionVoxelminZ; insideZ < thistotalPositionVoxelMAXZ; insideZ++)
                        {
                            for(var insideX = thistotalPositionVoxelminX; insideX < thistotalPositionVoxelMAXX; insideX++)
                            {
                                if(insideZ == length && insideX == width)
                                {
                                    return false;   
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return true;
        }
```

Here is our result:

[image: result of function above]

This really does provide an exact answer on if your object is touching something it should not be touching because of the point by point it processes.

I hope this helps!  Please feel free to use this at anytime.

Also note this really could effect `overhead/memory` usage if you are not careful on how you use this.  I am working on a way to better optimize this in the case of having hundred of objects to process.  So if you have any suggestions on modifying or adding to my existing code to accomplish this better and offer better performance in case of hundreds of objects passed, feel free provide details!